# Sorting from earliest to latest date

Tags: c#, datetime

How to loop every month's first date.

```
public struct stat{
public DateTime date;
}
```

I have a `List<stat>` that have a date property. I want to get the lowest and newest one by sorting. the first element is older and last is newer one.

I can easily got the first and second by order by.

What I want is get 1st date of every month in the between of both first (oldest ) and newest.

string ret = "";

```
    List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

    int breaker = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);

    stats = stats.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList();
    DateTime old = stats.First().Date;
    DateTime @new = stats.Last().Date;

    int diffdays = @new.Subtract(old).Days;

    DateTime loopd = DateTime.Now;

    for (int i = 0; i < diffdays; i = i + breaker)
    {
        loopd = loopd.AddDays(-breaker);
        dates.Add(loopd);
        if (loopd < old)
            Console.WriteLine("date" + old);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < dates.Count; j++)
    {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            DateTime ld= dates[0];
            stats.SelectMany(x => x.Date < @new && x.Date > dates[j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you going to write the sort code yourself? What is your ultimate aim?

Comment: Sorry but this seems to be  a request to write code for you. Do you have tried something and do you have any code to show?

Comment: Surely just thelist.OrderBy(s=>s.date) then use .First() and .Last() to get the oldest and newest? ... as the two answers now show (damn my slow typing :D)

Comment: Is there a point to wrapping `DateTime` in a `struct`?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get the lowest and newest one by sorting

I assume *lowest* means oldest.

```
stat oldest = stats.OrderBy(s => s.date).FirstOrDefault();
stat newest = stats.OrderByDescending(s => s.date).FirstOrDefault();
```

you could also use

```
stats.OrderBy(s => s.date).LastOrDefault();
```

to get the newest.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this:

```
List<stat> statList = new List<stat>();
...
var selectedItem = statList
                   .OrderBy(item => item.date)
                   .Select(l => l.last());
```

or you could use `OrderByDecending()` instead